# Contents of all tabs disappear after navigating to a page other than page with tabs and coming back

Tags: android, tabs

I have code that creates tabs dynamically.

This is my MyActivity.java:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
.
.
.
.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.audit_form_activity);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(page);

            JSONArray jssArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("AuditQuestions");
            int jsonArrLength = jssArray.length();

            no_of_categories = jsonArrLength;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrLength; i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildObj = jssArray.getJSONObject(i);


                categoryName.add(jsonChildObj.getString("categoryName"));


            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_categories);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener(viewPager));

    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_categories; i++) {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            adapter.addFragment(tab1, categoryName.get(i));

            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
            onTabSelectedListener(viewPager);
        }
    }

    private TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener onTabSelectedListener(final ViewPager pager) {
        return new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        };
    }

}
```

This is my adapter Pager.java:

```
public class Pager extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
    int mNumOfTabs;
    Fragment fragment = null;

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Pager(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

On removing this line from MyActivity.java , the content is there in tabs even after navigating away from tabs page and coming back:

```
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_categories);
```

But it doesn't solve the issue because the contents displayed in the tabs are inconsistent, i.e, contents that are supposed to appear in one tab appears on other tab.

I tried to solve it but with no success. May be it has to do with the life cycle of fragments?

How do I solve this?

Not able to find any solution for this. Please help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!